# How to optimize a mutli-dimensional array search routine (one condition per row)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, search, indexing, boolean-logic

Given a multi-dimensional array of data, I would like to identify the columns in which each row condition is satisfied per column. I have a working algorithm that I would like to further optimize. Whereas my method can take multiple conditions, the approach suggested via a post in Code Review does not. I would like to adapt the approach suggested in Code Review to take multiple conditions.

As an example, consider some sample data.

```
import numpy as np

def get_sample_data(nsample):
    """ This function returns a multi-dimensional integer array. """
    if nsample == 0:
        row_a = np.array([1, 4, 7, 3, 10, 3, 5, 1])
        row_b = np.array([2, 5, 30, 30, 10, 5, 5, 1])
        row_c = np.array([23, 21, 22, 23, 23, 25, 21, 23])
    elif nsample == 1:
        row_a = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
        row_b = row_a * 10
        row_c = row_a + 20
    data = np.array([row_a, row_b, row_c])
    return data

data = get_sample_data(0)
# data = get_sample_data(1)
```

I wrote a function to help simplify the process of assigning one of various conditions per row.

```
def search(condition, value, relation):
    """ This function returns the indices at which the array condition is satisfied. """
    if relation in ('equality', 'exact match'):
        res = np.where(condition == value)
    elif relation == 'not equal':
        res = np.where(condition != value)
    elif relation == 'greater than':
        res = np.where(condition > value)
    elif relation in ('less than', 'lesser than'):
        res = np.where(condition < value)
    elif relation == 'greater than or equal':
        res = np.where(condition >= value)
    elif relation in ('less than or equal', 'lesser than or equal'):
        res = np.where(condition <= value)
    elif relation == 'nearest':
        delta = np.abs(condition - value)
        res = np.where(delta == np.min(delta))
    elif relation == 'nearest forward':
        delta = condition - value
        try:
            res = np.where(delta == np.min(delta[delta >= 0]))
        except:
            raise ValueError("no forward-nearest match exists")
    elif relation == 'nearest backward':
        delta = value - condition
        try:
            res = np.where(delta == np.min(delta[delta >= 0]))
        except:
            raise ValueError("no backward-nearest match exists")
    elif relation == 'custom':
        res = np.where(condition)
    else:
        raise ValueError("the input search relation is invalid")
    return res
```

Below is my implementation, which works successfully.

```
def get_base(shape, value, dtype=int):
    """ This function returns a basemask, over which values may be overwritten. """
    if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
        res = np.ones(shape, dtype=dtype) * value
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        res = np.array([value for idx in range(np.prod(shape))]).reshape(shape)
    return res

def alternate_base(shape, key):
    """ This function returns one of two basemasks, each consisting of a single broadcast value. """
    if key % 2 == 0:
        value = 0.25
    else:
        value = 0.5
    return get_base(shape, value, dtype=float)

def my_method(ndata, search_value, search_relation):
    """ This method was adapted from a CodeReview and successfully works, but I would like to further optimize it. """
    if isinstance(search_relation, str):
        search_relation = (search_relation, search_relation, search_relation)
    elif len(search_relation) != 3:
        raise ValueError("search_relation should be a string or a collection of three relations")
    print("\nDATA SAMPLE:\n{}\n".format(ndata))
    print("SEARCH VALUE:    {}\nSEARCH RELATION:    {}\n".format(search_value, search_relation))
    bases = np.array([alternate_base(len(ndata.T), idx) for idx in range(len(ndata))])
    locs = np.array([search(condition=ndata[idx], value=search_value[idx], relation=search_relation[idx])[0] for idx in range(len(search_relation))])
    for base, loc in zip(bases, locs):
         base[loc] = 0
    condition = np.sum(bases, axis=0)
    idx_res = search(condition=condition, value=0, relation='equality')[0]
    val_res = np.array([ndata[idx][idx_res] for idx in range(len(ndata))])
    print("RESULTANT INDICES:\n{}\n".format(idx_res))
    print("RESULTANT VALUES:\n{}\n".format(val_res))
    if len(idx_res) == 0:
        raise ValueError("match not found for multiple conditions")
    return idx_res
```

The method above had slight changes made [based on this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189414/127168). The approach suggested in the review is below. But this method only covers the strict equality condition (`==`). **Is it possible to adapt it to take multiple conditions?**

```
def martin_fabre_method(ndata, search_value):
    """ """
    print("\nNDATA:\n{}\n".format(ndata))
    print("SEARCH VALUE:    {}\n".format(search_value))
    mask = ndata == [[i] for i in search_value]
    idx_res = mask.all(axis=0)
    if not np.any(idx_res):
        raise ValueError("match not found for multiple conditions")
    val_res = ndata[:, idx_res]
    print("RESULTANT INDICES:\n{}\n".format(idx_res))
    print("RESULTANT VALUES:\n{}\n".format(val_res))
    return idx_res
```

To run the algorithm, one can copy-paste the above and run the following:

```
# my_method(data, search_value=(7, 30, 22), search_relation='equality')
# my_method(data, search_value=(7, 5, 22), search_relation=('less than', 'equality', 'less than'))
martin_fabre_method(data, search_value=(7, 30, 22))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the first line from my Code Review answer with something like this:

```
def get_mask(data, search_value, comparison):
    comparisons = {
        'equal': '__eq__',
        'equality': '__eq__',
        'exact match': '__eq__',
        'greater than': '__gt__',
        'greater than or equal': '__ge__',
        'less than': '__lt__',
        'less than or equal': '__le__',
        'lesser than': '__lt__',
        'lesser than or equal': '__le__',
        'not equal': '__ne__',
    }
    try:
        comp = getattr(data, comparisons[comparison])
        return comp(search_value)
    except KeyError:
        pass
    if comparison == 'custom':
        return np.where(condition)

    delta = data - search_value
    if comparison == 'nearest':
        delta = np.abs(delta)
    elif comparison == 'nearest forward':
        delta = np.where(delta >= 0, delta, np.inf).min(axis=1, keepdims=True)
        print(min_)
    elif comparison == 'nearest backward':
        delta = -np.where(delta <= 0, delta, -np.inf)
    if (delta == np.inf).all(axis=0).any():
        raise ValueError("no %s match exists for searchvalue %s" % (comparison, repr(search_value)))
#     print(repr(delta))
#     print(min_)
    return delta ==  delta.min(axis=1, keepdims=True)

def martin_fabre_method(ndata, search_value, comparison):
    """ """
    print("\nNDATA:\n{}\n".format(ndata))
    print("SEARCH VALUE:    {}\n".format(search_value))
    mask = get_mask(ndata, search_value, comparison)
    idx_res = mask.all(axis=0)
    if not np.any(idx_res):
        raise ValueError("match not found for multiple conditions")
    val_res = ndata[:, idx_res]
    print("RESULTANT INDICES:\n{}\n".format(idx_res))
    print("RESULTANT VALUES:\n{}\n".format(val_res))
    return idx_res
```

## Alternative with `operator`

The first part can be made more clear using the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module:

```
def get_mask(data, search_value, comparison):
    import operator
    comparisons = {
        'equal': operator.eq,
        'equality': operator.eq,
        'exact match': operator.eq,
        'greater than': operator.gt,
        'greater than or equal': operator.ge,
        'less than': operator.lt,
        'less than or equal': operator.le,
        'lesser than': operator.lt,
        'lesser than or equal': operator.le,
        'not equal': operator.ne,
    }
    try:
        return comparisons[comparison](data, search_value)
    ....
```

Comment: I will have a chance to play with this later in the day, thank you for the help. If I want to learn more about double underscore methods such as __eq__ or __gt__, are there alternatives to “magic methods” that I can look up? I was under the impression attributes only applied to classes, though I’m guessing these will apply to the numpy ndarray class in this case.

Comment: a lot of the operators (`==`, `<`, , `+`, etc.) and special functions (`len(), str()`, ...) are implemented by the class (or object) providing these dunder method. You can read about those special methods on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) or search for `python dunder` on the internet

Comment: the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) is sometimes clearer than working with the dunder methods directly